# ModuleNotFoundError while creating exe file from pyinstaller

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, pyautogui

I am trying to generate the `.exe` file from the python script that I have written. I am running `pyinstaller --onefile script_name.py` in Acacnonda Promp (while being in the folder with the script itself) and it runs with no errors. However, when I am trying to run it I face this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'
[15480] Failed to execute script script_name
```

I have tried running it in CMD (not in anaconda prompt) but faced with same issue.

Comment: have you installed `pyautogui` in your activate conda environment?

Comment: yes, i am installing it both in the script itself and before runninf pyinstaller

Comment: Why it is tagged by pywinauto? I’m not a pyautogui developer.

Comment: is your pyinstaller is also installed in conda environment activated?